# PHP increment operator returns incorrect result in formula

Tags: javascript, php, operators

I was playing the challenges on SoloLearn and I found this:

```
var x = 5;
document.write(x * x++);
// will output 25
```

but if we write the same thing in PHP:

```
$x = 5;
echo $x * $x++;
// it will output 30!
```

And this is something, isn't it?

So how can the average programmer explain this to his grandma?

Comment: Javascript is just evaluating the expressions in order, left-to-right, post-incrementing as normal, but PHP is weird - the behavior you note is undefined, it may output 30 *or* 25.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is [Undefined order of evaluation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in PHP:

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code.